# Laravel PHPUnit loading .env.testing file

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, phpdotenv

I have some problems with getting Laravel to load the proper .env file for my testcases.
I'm using PHPUnit with the following var set in phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>./app/Http/routes.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

In my .env.testing file i have:

```
APP_ENV=testing
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

And i have his connection set up under config/database.php:

```
'sqlite' => [
     'driver' => 'sqlite',
     'database' => ':memory:',
     'prefix' => ''
]
```

It just isn't loading the .env.testing file. If i do this in my TestCase.php:

```
dd(env('APP_ENV'));
```

I still get "development" from my .env file

I have also tried using:

```
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');
```

Like suggested in the thread [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/using-several-env-files-within-my-app-general-and-testing/replies/126618)

Does anyone have an idea to what could be wrong?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson i'm using version 5.2

Comment: Can you share your full phpunit.xml file?

Comment: @Sandeesh i added the phpunit.xml file

Comment: I was having the same problem and was commenting here a workaround but then I realized that I'm having this in my bootstrap script rather than the actual tests. In my case the problem is that `<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>` has no effect in the bootstrap script. I had to add `putenv('APP_ENV=testing');` manually before creating the application. If this is not the case for you, you may be able to use this as a workaround.

Answer (score 7):

My problem was quite similar. Env file .env.testing was not read at all.
I tried to put some var_dump everywhere in my test file, everything was ok but even a var_dump(env("APP_NAME")) was null.

I figured to type a "php artisan config:clear" and everything was back to normal.
Not sure what I've done but it worked for me :)

Comment: I tried `php artisan config:cache` but it doesn't helped. When i tried `php artisan config:clear` it worked. I don't have any idea what is difference (clear should be included inside cache command) but it somehow works

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` will remove the cached config.php file and force the app to use what is defined in the configs and .env

Comment: The problem with `artisan config:clear` or `artisan optimize:clear` is that if you have a permission problem to delete files/folders it will fail silently.

Comment: Thanks @Tyteck, been banging my head against a wall trying to get phpunit to read the correct env files. tried artisan config:clear as many posts suggested and it did nothing, after seeing your posts i ran with sudo, sudo php artisan config:clear and it now it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To load the `.env.testing` file, you have to execute the artisan command with `--env=testing`

Answer (score -2):

Are you running Feature or Unit tests?  I think unit tests are only supposed to work on mocks, while Feature tests may persist to the database.